# synchronization, remove from collection

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

I am working on website with games and I have map of players and their virtual tables.

```
private final ConcurrentMap<Player, List<Table>> tableOfPlayers = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

and method to remove table

```
private void removeTable(Player player,Table table) {
    if(tableOfPlayers.get(player).size() == 1) {
        tableOfPlayers.remove(player);
    } else {
        tableOfPlayers.get(player).remove(table);
    }

}
```

Is there any good way to solve this check-then-act idiom, because now it isn't thread-safe.
I know that I can synchronize both add and remove method, but I am wondering if it is possible to make it better. The reason why I check if size is equal to 1 is that if player have only one active table and I decide to remove I no longer need this player in my map.

Comment: Please explain what it is you're trying to accomplish. Is the issue that you want to remove the player from the table if and only if the player's "size"(?) is one? Your naming of the map is confusing (a "table of players" would usually be something like `Set<Player>`), and it's hard to determine what the appropriate business logic is here.